# How to manually change the position of nodes in VisNetwork in R

Tags: r, visnetwork, r-neo4j

I have a problem with VisNetwork. I created a graph in R and each time when I click on the node and move it to other place, it comes back to where it was before. Is there any possibility to rearrange network manually? I'd like to move some nodes to the other place or to change the length of edges between some nodes, so that it would be more transparent.

Comment: Use library d3Network to avoid issues

Comment: Hi @Arunkumarmahesh is it possible to achieve something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65583493/vis-network-define-node-location) in d3Network ?

Answer (score 1):

At least two possibilities :

Use `vis.js` to compute coordinate (default) and then after disable physics

```
require(visNetwork)
nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:3)
edges <- data.frame(from = c(1,2), to = c(1,3))
visNetwork(nodes, edges)  %>% 
  visEvents(stabilizationIterationsDone="function () {this.setOptions( { physics: false } );}")
```

Or Use `igraph` to compute coordinate. It's faster, and physics is disabled automatically

`visNetwork(nodes, edges)  %>% visIgraphLayout()`

You can also set coordinate before render with `x` & `y` columns in `nodes`

Comment: Can you explain how to manually set the coordinates? I've created `x` and `y` values in `nodes` but it does not seem to follow them at all.

Comment: Can you add an example on how to achieve it? Would be super useful! :)

Comment: is it possible to achieve something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65583493/vis-network-define-node-location) with igraph ?appreciate if you can provide an example

Comment: Greetings, could any of you set the coordinates manually?