# Place nodes explicitly with visNetwork (or an Alternative)

Tags: r, igraph, graph-theory, visnetwork

**How can I explicitly place `nodes` on a `visNetwork` graph?**

**Or: How can I recreate that graphic in R using `visNetwork` or an alternative?**

[image]

*Background: The ultimate goal is to represent [Causal Loop Diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_loop_diagram) coming from [Vensim](http://vensim.com/) files. Placing the nodes explicitly is just the first (crucial) step, because in Causal Loop Diagrams the visual mapping of nodes is part of the information (unlike in general graph theory). So if anybody has advice on the bigger picture aka. 'Bringing Causal Loop Diagram Modeling to R', I'll be more than happy.*

What I tried:

```
library("visNetwork")

nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:3, label = c("one", "two", "three"))
edges <- data.frame(from = c(1,1,2), to = c(2,3,1))

visNetwork(nodes, edges, width = "100%", title = nodes$labels, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% visEdges(arrows = "to")
```

which plots something like (exact layout will change, because of random seed):

[image]

With the Q&A from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38265713/how-to-manually-change-the-position-of-nodes-in-visnetwork-in-r) I  tried to place nodes manually by setting `x` and `y` values.

```
library("visNetwork")

nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:3, label = c("one", "two", "three"), x = c(0,1,2), y = c(0,1,2))
edges <- data.frame(from = c(1,1,2), to = c(2,3,1))

visNetwork(nodes, edges, width = "100%", title = nodes$labels, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% visEdges(arrows = "to")
```

which plots:

[image]

..and I really don't understand what's the correspondance between `x`, `y` and the placing on the screen..

Also I could not find anything in the [docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/visNetwork/versions/2.0.4/topics/visLayout) for `visLayout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ggraph` instead of `visNetwork` simplifies things.

```
library(ggraph)
library(igraph)

g <- make_graph(edges = c(1,2,2,1,1,3))
V(g)$name <- c('one', 'two', 'three')

ggraph(g, layout = 'manual', node.positions = data.frame(x = c(1,1,2), y = c(2,1,2.1))) + 
  geom_edge_arc(aes(start_cap = label_rect(node1.name),
                    end_cap = label_rect(node2.name)),
                 angle_calc = 'along',
                 label_dodge = unit(2.5, 'mm'),
                 arrow = arrow(length = unit(4, 'mm'))) + 
  geom_node_text(aes(label = name, x = x, y = y))
```

This plots[image]

which is (apart from gridlines and colours) what I was searching for.

Comment: is it possible to generate something [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65583493/vis-network-define-node-location)

Answer (score 3):

It somehow turns out, that the `x` and `y` args are not working. Here a solution:

```
library("visNetwork")

nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:3, label = c("one", "two", "three"))
edges <- data.frame(from = c(1,1,2), to = c(2,3,1))

coords <- as.matrix(data.frame(x = c(0,1,2),
                               y = c(0,1,2),
                               stringsAsFactors = FALSE))

visNetwork(nodes, edges, width = "100%", title = nodes$labels) %>%
    visNodes() %>%
    visOptions(highlightNearest = TRUE) %>%
    visInteraction(navigationButtons = TRUE,
                   dragNodes = TRUE, dragView = TRUE,
                   zoomView = FALSE) %>%
    visEdges(arrows = 'to') %>%
    visIgraphLayout(layout = "layout.norm", layoutMatrix = coords)
```

For history see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47630378/5784831).
Perhaps these links might be helpful for what you want to achive: [causaleffect](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/causaleffect/vignettes/causaleffect.pdf) and [plot.CLD](https://rdrr.io/github/jarrod-dalton/causalloop/man/plot.CLD.html)

Comment: Thx for pointing me to the `layoutMatrix` option. This helps placing nodes explicitly. IWhen I run your code, however, all the arrows are plotted as straight lines and therefore vice-versa arrows cover themselves up (contrary to what my goal is, see picture..). Do you know how to plot the arrows as bended lines?

Comment: @Christoph, can we generate something like this [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65583493/vis-network-define-node-location)